# npm "failed to parse json"

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, npm

When I'm trying to install express with npm I always get the following error:

```
Failed to parse json
No data, empty input at 1:1
File: /root/.npm/inherits/2.0.1/package/package.json
Failed to parse package.json data.
package.json must be actual JSON, not just JavaScript.

This is not a bug in npm.
Tell the package author to fix their package.json file. JSON.parse
```

What am I doing wrong?

```
 sudo npm install -g express
```

OS is Ubuntu 12.04 (precise) armhf

Comment: It may also be worth checking for trailing commas in `package.json` that was my (embarrassing) problem

Answer (score 103, accepted):

Thanks to [Jivings](https://stackoverflow.com/u/334274) from [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31454607//48523983#comment50876342_31454607):

```
npm cache clean
```

solved the problem.

Comment: for npm@5 just add `npm cache clean --force`

Comment: Be aware that this is only valid for older versions of NPM. For instance, I received the following while using a newer version: `npm ERR! As of npm@5, the npm cache self-heals from corruption issues and data extracted from the cache is guaranteed to be valid. If you want to make sure everything is consistent, use 'npm cache verify' instead. On the other hand, if you're debugging an issue with the installer, you can use "npm install --cache /tmp/empty-cache" to use a temporary cache instead of nuking the actual one.`

Answer (score 14):

I had the same problem but "npm cache clean" didnt resolve it for me. I had to go back to my package.json and realize i had comma where it shouldn't i suppose as shown below:

```
},
  "devDependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.15.3",
    "bootstrap-sass": "^3.3.7",
    "cross-env": "^3.2.4",
    "jquery": "^3.1.1",
    "laravel-mix": "0.*",
    "lodash": "^4.17.4",
    "vue": "^2.1.10",
  }
```

after  the "vue..." so I deleted that and every went back to normal. So it is **worth checking the package.json file first before running** `npm cache clean`

Comment: ya this was my problem and i just deleted the comma

Comment: fixed it for me

Answer (score 5):

Mostly, this error is due to a syntax error in package.json file.
In my case, the opening curly brace for dependencies object in package.json was missing:-

Code--------------------------------

```
{
  "name": "psrxjs",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": 
    "rxjs": "^5.4.3"
  }
}
```

---

Comment: ya i had a comma added to the end of a dependencies and it would not work until i deleted one comma

Answer (score 4):

In Laravel project:

1. Delete 'node_modules' folder;
2. npm cache clean
3. npm update

Answer (score 4):

I solved the issue using below steps:

1. Delete `node_modules` folder
2. Delete `package-lock.json` file
3. Run  `npm install`
4. Run `npm start`

Comment: Removing a `package-lock.json` will break project dependencies that are locked to a specific version. This could have unintended effect on a codebase and lead to breakage. IMO don't ever remove your package-lock.json.

Comment: This works! I found out that deleting node_modules was not even necessary. The package-lock.json was corrupt and running `npm install` will re-generate a new one.

Answer (score 3):

You could get this error from not doing `npm init`.

Answer (score 2):

I also got the same error message while run `npm install`, first run `npm package.json` to check errors in package.json file, if not then run `npm cache clean`

Answer (score 1):

I faced this problem several times before I got used to using NPM. Most off the time it was because I failed to use npm init before npm install

Comment: Answer flagged as low Quality. I disagree - I think it's very likely to be WRONG, but I think it's perfectly legitimate as an answer.

Comment: This is ridiculous! Publish my answer. I was faced with the same problem and it had to do with exactly what I wrote above. I found the solution and then I wanted to go back and share it and I am ridiculed. Very strange!

Answer (score 1):

For me the issue was fixed by changing the name of the package
from

```
"name": "portfolio"
```

to

```
"name": "portfolio2"
```

Answer (score 0):

I experienced a similar issue today after updating Node on Windows 10. My local build tasks started failing and upon investigation I saw all these errors in my dependency package.json files. None of them were valid JSON anymore and I was seeing messages like:

```
npm WARN Failed to parse json
npm WARN Unexpected token '\u0019' at 1:1
npm WARN ������2�����bE�;���1L �\5�e���k2?��,?;��쏏a��(T��w��+I��/�6�P} ��i�|e�
npm WARN ^
```

in my console.

This story has a happy ending as it turns out that new Node doesn't play nice with old NPM and updating NPM to version 5 solved the problem. Hope this helps other folks who may experience this variation on this issue.

Answer (score 0):

In my case 
`Missing a comma somewhere in a package.json` Check your package.json file.
 After that `sudo npm install`

**or**

To clean the cache memory.
`sudo npm cache clean`

Comment: This answer came in low quality post. Add some explanation even though code is self explanatory

Answer (score 0):

The following bash script fixes the problem automatically

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
echo -e '#!/usr/bin/env bash' > npm_install.sh
cat npm-debug.log | grep 'error File:' | sed -n 's:.*error File\: \(.*\):echo "Removing \1"\nrm -f \1\necho "Cleaning npm cache"\nnpm cache clean\necho "Reinstalling npm"\nnpm install\n./npm_reinstall.sh:p' >> npm_install.sh
chmod +x npm_install.sh
./npm_install.sh
```

It should be saved to npm_reinstall.sh
and granted execution permissions using

```
chmod +x npm_reinstall.sh
```

The script is preforming the following tasks:

1. Looking for an error File : in npm-debug.log using grep
2. Using sed to generate the fix commands 3-5 only if there are errors
3. Removing the empty file *rm -f* /1 = file path from the first group in regular expression *.*error File: (.*)*
4. Cleaning npm cache *npm cache clean*
5. Reinstalling npm *npm install*
6. Running ./npm_reinstall.sh recursively till no errors are found

More information about npm install can be found at [npm-install command documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to [Pank's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1402846) [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31454716/5515861), if you encounter this kind of error

```
npm ERR! code EJSONPARSE
npm ERR! JSON.parse Failed to parse json
npm ERR! JSON.parse Unexpected token } in JSON at position 550 while parsing near '...eact": "^7.12.4",
npm ERR! JSON.parse   },
npm ERR! JSON.parse   "dependencies":...'
npm ERR! JSON.parse Failed to parse package.json data.
npm ERR! JSON.parse package.json must be actual JSON, not just JavaScript.
```

You need to make sure your `package.json` is a valid json, not a javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Please check with unused white spaces inside package.json file, it might cause by extra white spaces.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be did some change in **package.json** and that is not valid

1. Delete **node_modules**
2. Delete **package.json**
3. Create a new NPM package with

`npm init`

4. install all of your package once again

`npm install express`

Answer (score 0):

For those of you who are new to this like me, I forgot to initialize my JSON package with the npm init command.

Answer (score 0):

remove any unnecessary comments, the error you referred occurs usually due to the syntax error. Or if this won't help, try to clean the cache by "npm cache clean".

Answer (score 0):

1.Basically it comes for wrong placement of comma so remove comma at wrong position(esp error occurs for placing comma(,) before closing flower brace('}') in package.json so look into it. This is one solution

2. Run

> sudo npm cache clean

3. 

> sudo chown -R 1000:1000 "...path/.npm"

Answer (score -1):

Don't forget to edit your package.json, escpeially the dependencies.

For example, one of my chatting room projects needs the following content in package.json:

```
{
    "name":"chatrooms",
    "version":"0.0.1",
    "description":"Minimalist multi-room chat server",
    "dependencies":{
        "socket.io":"~0.9.6",
        "mime":"~1.2.7"
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to open your txt editor and select "plain text" for the package.json then re-save. Sometimes issue is overlooked and simple things are holding the answer.